# how to get variable value from liquid in elsa workflow?

Tags: elsa-workflows

I'm trying to get a variable's value from liquid in Elsa workflow but it's not working,
it just shows the variable's name in c# code.

[image: Variable stats in runtime]

Answer (score 0):

The value you are showing in your screenshot is correct: the `Body` property provides you with the unparsed contents.

To get the parsed content, use the `expressionEvaluator` service you have there in your `OnExecuteAsync` method. Which you already do: just make sure to inspect (and use) the `body` variable.